# Find number of flips of transposition $(i \ j)$.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Suppose that $(i \ j) \in S_n$ is a transposition and that $i < j$.

How would it be possible to find an expression for the number of flips of $(i \ j)$?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'flip'?

Comment: A flip x an element of Sn is a pair i,j such that i < j and  x(j) < x(i) @JosephMartin

Comment: Are you talking about [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics))? Have you tried computing some examples concretely by counting?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think so but I've been using Dummit&a Foote and I feel as though inversions are referred to as flips in that book. E.g. The number of flips for x= (1,3,4)(2,5) an element of S5 would be 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your definition in the comments, the number of flips of an element $\sigma \in S_n$ is $nf := |\{i, j < n| i < j, x(j) < x(i)\}|$. In that case, the question seems to have an easy solution:

Suppose $(ij)$ is your transposition ($i < j$). It swaps $j$ and $i$ and leaves all other elements on their place. Now, suppose $p$ and $q$ are such numbers, that $p < q$ and $(ij)(p) > (ij)(q)$. This definitely can not happen in case, when neither $p$ nor $q$ belong to $\{i, j\}$. Neither can they in case, when $p, q \leq i$ or $p, q \geq j$. Now, suppose $p = i$ and $q \neq j$. Then $i < q < j$. Suppose $q = j$, $p \neq i$. That also results in $i < p < j$. Those cases and $p = i$, $q = j$ are the only possible ones. So $nf((ij)) = 2|\{p|i < p < j\}| + 1 = 2(|j - i| - 1) + 1 = 2|i - j| - 1$

Comment: Thank you! Makes so much sense now that I can see the steps .

Answer (score -1):

The inversion number (what you call the number of flips) is the number of crossings in the arrow diagram of the permutation. This is $1$.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)#Inversion_number) for more.